# Laravel deployment configuration

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, virtualhost

In my `httpd.conf` file I have:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/my-domain.com/public
ServerName my-domain.ir
<Directory /var/www/my-domain.com/public>
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options All
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and in my `laravel_project_root/public` directory I have an `.htaccess` file which has:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks

    RewriteEngine On

    # Force http to https
    #RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the result is:

**Service Unavailable**

The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

When I use an `index.html` file and change that `DirectoryIndex index.php` to `DirectoryIndex index.html` it works! but I don't know what is my fault in these configurations that php files doesn't load.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

**Update**
`error_log`

```
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:15.751947 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 50730] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:15.812330 2019] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 50730] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:15.813030 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 50730] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:16.000310 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 50730] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/7.2.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:16.000381 2019] [core:notice] [pid 50730] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:21.644207 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 50732] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:21.644312 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 50732] [client 2.176.232.178:61732] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:22.552480 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 50734] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:22.552599 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 50734] [client 2.176.232.178:61733] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:23.256763 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 50735] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: FCGI: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:9000 (*) failed
[Wed Feb 06 09:42:23.256860 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 50735] [client 2.176.232.178:61734] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Is there something written to your server's error log?

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: Well, on your server, mostly at `/var/log/apache`

Comment: I couldn't find that file, but instead I found `/var/log/httpd/error_log` and clear all its contents and refresh that page and the result was what I updated.

Comment: So, what's your conclusion from reading that error log?

Comment: I'm not professional at this field!

Comment: There are tons of questions out there about that error - mostly, its about FPM being wrongly configured. Please attach your FPM configuration to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188004/discussion-between-kodfire-and-nico-haase).

Comment: Make sure that the maintenance mode from Laravel is disabled. Just run php artisan up

Comment: Thank you all, I just hadn't enabled `php-fpm`, Nico Haase helped to find it out where the problem is. Now it's working :)